# Distribution of $\int X_t \,dt$ if we know distribution of $X_t$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $B(t)$ is the standard Wiener process on [0,1], how should one go about finding the distribution of some random variable $Z$ defined by, say
$$
Z(\omega) = \int_0^1B_t(\omega)\,dt\quad ?$$
Something like $Z \sim \text{normal}(0,\int_0^1t\,dt)$ seems too good to be true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random variable $Z$ is Gaussian as a linear functional of Gaussian process, thus we only need to compute the mean and the variance of $Z$:
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left(Z\right) = \int_0^1 \mathbb{E}\left(B_t\right) \mathrm{d}t = 0
$$
$$
   \mathbb{Var}\left(Z\right) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \mathbb{Cov}\left(B_s, B_t\right) \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d} s = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \min\left(t,s\right) \, \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d} s = \frac{1}{3}
$$
Thus $Z \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu = 0, \sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.